# Looking for an extensive gallery of Mathematica's 2D graphics

Tags: graphics, reference-request

I am having a hard time conveying to my co-workers why I think that what they consider "advanced", "high-quality" scientific graphics<sup>1</sup> does not hold a candle to what one could do already do with *Mathematica* back in the late 80's, let alone now.

It would bolster my case if I could show them a single gallery of the sort of stuff that only *Mathematica* can do, thanks to the generality of its conception of graphics.

Over the years I've seen zillions of impressive *Mathematica* graphics demos, but I'm having a hard time finding a big, easily-browsable collection that shows off *Mathematica*'s power as a platform for generating scientific graphics.

NB: I am particularly interested in 2D plots, mostly because the libraries whose feebleness I'm trying to demonstrate can do only that.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For the sake of politeness, I won't name the software and the graphics libraries that my co-workers are so impressed by.</sup>

Comment: The "competition" better not be *Matlab*.... hah!  Just type "mathematica graphics examples" into Google image search for a start.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://members.wolfram.com/jeffb/visualization/)?

Comment: it might be better if you did name the software

Comment: I always found Trott Graphics book for Mathematica impressive. (even though I do not understand most of the code there as it is too advanced for me) http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/5352/  also [Graphica 1](http://www.amazon.com/Graphica-1-John-Bonadies/dp/1568811063) if you have it. It has amazing Mathematica Graphics, also by same author.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch: fine: it's the Matlab-inspired Matplotlib library for Python.  This library is considered the "standard" graphics library for Python, and the Python world is generally mighty impressed by it, which means that there's little hope for anything better.  Matplotlib started out as a side-project hack (by its author's own description), and it "grew" into the Python standard.  IMO, the design of something as important as a language's representation of graphics needs more careful thought than what went into Matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just to say it ... have a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

A great source anyway is the Wolfram Blog, but in particular I like [The Ultimate Univariate Probability Distribution Explorer](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/02/01/the-ultimate-univariate-probability-distribution-explorer/).

You can find [A plot gallery for Mathematica 9](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=4788), if the author sees this he makes possibly an update to v10.

The http://www.mathematica-journal.com/ is just great to show off.

On http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ you'll find tons and tons of the stuff you looking for.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ move to Visualization & Graphics

And because it's never good to be impressed by the achievements of others, I would like to allow me the impudence and cite a quote:

> “An impression is for the writer what an experiment is for the
>   scientist, except that for the scientist the work of the intelligence
>   precedes it, and for the writer it comes afterwards.” ― Marcel Proust,
>   Time Regained